# nextjs/socket.io video chat does not turn on the camera of some devices

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, next.js, video-capture

I decided to add video chat to my existing nextjs application and ran into 2 problems.

Stack: nextjs@10, socket.io@4, socket.io-client@4, express

Since I'm completely new to this, I looked at a number of options and chose this one to explore(with my own little changes, including the nextjs backend feature): [video-chat-webrtc](https://github.com/maks1mp/video-chat-webrtc)

Localhost in my comp: all OK. Test server(with ELB AWS) next variants:

1. I create room(video+audio+chat), Canada user joined from Chrome(see me/self camera not ON, audio+chat => all OK)
2. I create room and join from phone => all OK, joined from another device(notebook) => case Chrome: all OK, but not translation from notebook camera, joined from Firefox => not translation anything, only chat and sound.

So sound and chat messages are always transmitted, there are problems with camera capture(there was a request to allow access - all allowed)
In console:

> Error getting userMedia: DOMException: Starting videoinput failed

Part of the code responsible for capturing video and audio:

```
useEffect(() => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: {
            width: 1280,
            height: 720
        },
        audio: true
    }).then(stream => {
        console.log('STREAM OBJECT: ', stream);
        localMediaStream.current = stream;
        addNewClient(LOCAL_VIDEO, () => {
            const localVideoElement = peerMediaElements.current[LOCAL_VIDEO];
    
            if (localVideoElement) {
                localVideoElement.volume = 0; // off self sound micro
                localVideoElement.srcObject = stream;
            }
        });
        socket.emit(SOCKET_ACTIONS.JOIN_ROOM, {room: roomID});
    }).catch(e => {
        console.warn('Error getting userMedia:', e);
        socket.emit(SOCKET_ACTIONS.JOIN_ROOM, {room: roomID})
    });
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot access to camera from two different browsers at the same time.

From [getUserMedia - Cannot access camera from two browsers at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43307162/getusermedia-cannot-access-camera-from-two-browsers-at-the-same-time)

> This is a limitation on Windows. On Mac OS you can use the same camera
> in multiple applications at the same time but not in Windows
> unfortunately.

I am using kali Linux and I cannot access either.